# How to avoid my animated image clipping the sticky header?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, react-spring

I made a sticky header but I use react-spring animation that is definitely the culprit here, so is it possible to modify it somehow so that it doesn't clip with the header or is that part of the fundamental structure? I feel like it should be possible to make configure it so that it doesn't go OVER other elements and instead goes under. Here are a couple pictures:

The issue here
[image: clipping]

Here is how it deals with text (as it should):

[image: text]

Here is the relevant js code of the animation and the .css code for it too:

JS:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./RegionCard.css"
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'


const calc = (x, y) => [-(y - window.innerHeight / 2) / 30, (x - window.innerWidth / 2) / 30, 1.1]
const trans = (x, y, s) => `perspective(500px) rotateX(${x}deg) rotateY(${y}deg) scale(${s})`

const RegionCard = ({regionName, imageUrl}) => {
  const [props, set] = useSpring(() => ({ xys: [0, 0, 1], config: { mass: 5, tension: 350, friction: 40 } }))
  return (
    <animated.div
      class="card"
      onMouseMove={({ clientX: x, clientY: y }) => set({ xys: calc(x, y) })}
      onMouseLeave={() => set({ xys: [0, 0, 1] })}
      style={{backgroundImage: imageUrl, transform: props.xys.interpolate(trans) }}
    ><h1>{regionName}</h1></animated.div>
  )
}

export default RegionCard
```

CSS:

```
.card {

  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://www.steppestravel.com/app/uploads/2019/06/greater-caucasus-mountain-range-upper-svaneti-georgia.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px -5px rgba(19, 153, 71, 0.3);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  will-change: transform;
  
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 100px -10px rgba(19, 153, 71, 0.3);
}

h1{
  color: #79d490;
}
```

Comment: have you add a positive z-index to your header?

Comment: God damn that's what it was didn't even know it was a thing thanks.